# How to access BaseActivity ToolBar in Activity in android

Tags: android

i want to access toolBar in MyActivity which extends BaseActivity can access  Toolbar in MainActivity.

BaseActivity

```
  public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container_base);
            Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    }
    }
```

MyActivity

```
 public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // here i want to access BaseActivity  Toolbar
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your toolbar with [setSupportActionBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)) in your `BaseActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container_base);
   Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Then get the toolbar from [getSupportActionBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#getSupportActionBar()) after `super.onCreate` in `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
}
```

You can't cast an `ActionBar` to `Toolbar`, but if you really want to access to the toolbar, then change it to an instance variable:

```
protected Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container_base);
    toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    // ...
```

With `protected` modifier you can access to `toolbar` in your `MainActivity`.

Comment: how to type cast actionBar as toolbar can we ? @Aaron

Comment: No, you can't. I wouldn't suggest that but if you really want to, you can declare your toolbar as instance variable with protected modifier.